How to Expose C++ Qt WebView and Window Functions to Python Without Using PySide or PyQt?
I'm working on a project where I need to integrate a Qt6 WebView into Python. The WebView should allow dynamic control from Python, including:

Setting the window size and style (e.g., resizing, full-screen,
borderless).

Loading HTML content or a URL dynamically.

Interacting with JavaScript in the WebView.


What I Want to Achieve:
Dynamically set window properties (e.g., resize(800, 600), borderless mode, etc.).
Load either:

Raw HTML content (loadHtml).

A remote URL (loadUrl).

Execute and interact with JavaScript in the WebView (e.g., calling JS
functions or retrieving results).

Expose all these functionalities to Python without relying on PySide
or PyQt due to licensing concerns.


What I’ve Tried:

I’ve attempted to use pybind11 to expose a custom C++ class that
wraps QApplication and QWebEngineView. Here's an example of my
pybind11 bindings:

#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QString>

namespace py = pybind11;

class WebView {
public:
    WebView() {
        int argc = 0;
        char *argv[] = {nullptr};
        app = std::make_unique<QApplication>(argc, argv);
        view = std::make_unique<QWebEngineView>();
    }

    void resize(int width, int height) {
        view->resize(width, height);
    }

    void setHtml(const std::string &html) {
        view->setHtml(QString::fromStdString(html));
    }

    void setUrl(const std::string &url) {
        view->setUrl(QUrl(QString::fromStdString(url)));
    }

    void exec() {
        view->show();
        app->exec();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<QApplication> app;
    std::unique_ptr<QWebEngineView> view;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(qt_webview, m) {
    py::class_<WebView>(m, "WebView")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("resize", &WebView::resize)
        .def("setHtml", &WebView::setHtml)
        .def("setUrl", &WebView::setUrl)
        .def("exec", &WebView::exec);
}


The code compiles fine, and I cannot load basic HTML and URLs in the
WebView from Python due to ImportError: /home/red-x/Documents/GUIEngine/MyQtWebViewApp/qt_webview.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: qt_version_ta. However:


I cannot tweak window styles (e.g., borderless or full-screen).
Ubuntu

I can't execute or retrieve JavaScript results from Python.

I feel my approach isn't complete or robust for all the features I
need.


Constraints:

No PySide or PyQt: I need a solution without these libraries because
of their licensing restrictions.

Why pybind11?: It fits my requirements for lightweight and
license-compliant bindings.


Questions:

How can I expose Qt's window and WebView functionalities (e.g.,
styles, JavaScript interaction) to Python using pybind11?

Is there a better way to handle this integration without relying on
PySide or PyQt?

Are there examples or open-source projects that achieve something
similar?


Environment:
OS:  Windows 10 or Ubuntu 20.04
Qt Version: 6.4.2
Python Version: 3.12
Compiler: g++ with C++17

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Show your CMakeLists.txt or similar file

Also show your .py
